# how to align column to the right?

Tags: angularjs, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am getting my head around twitter bootstrap 3 and specifically the column setup. I got a 2 columns on the same line:

```
<!--datetime row-->
  <div>
    <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
      <label for="">Title:</label>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown"
                aria-expanded="true">
          Dropdown
          <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
          <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
      why is this left instead of right aligned??

    </div>
  </div>
```

The problem is I cannot get the second column to sit to the right where the dropdown is. So I would like the dropdown in the first column and in the second column the 'why is this...' text. What causes this? Here is a ref to the full snippet: http://plnkr.co/edit/tufLd2?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add ' `text-right` to your `<div class="col-md-6 form-group">`
please see here

http://plnkr.co/edit/rUAdxLJ6ExKZYFbkveuC?p=preview

and if you want to have column for 50% of screen even on small devices

change `col-md-6` to `col-xs-6`

http://plnkr.co/edit/RxPx0zzT5YmodepQ3zIj?p=preview

Comment: hi I changed the questiondescription slightly to make it more understandable. thanks.

Comment: @Pindakaas is that http://plnkr.co/edit/RxPx0zzT5YmodepQ3zIj?p=preview not what you wanted ?

Comment: nope I would like to have the whole column on the right like specified

Comment: @Pindakaas so I'm bit confused can you draw that ?

Comment: @Pindakaas there was few closing tags missed, columns tags should always be wrapped by row tag, and if you want to have 2 columns on small screen you can use col-xs instead col-md

Answer (score 0):

This might solve the problem

```
<div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 form-group">
      <label for="">Title:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 form-group  text-right">
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown"
            aria-expanded="true">
            Dropdown
            <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>

            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
      why is this left instead of right aligned??
    </div>
</div>
```

[Live Demo](https://cg6.tutorialspoint.com/embed/1898/NKuyi47j)

Answer (score -1):

```
<!--datetime row-->
  <div **class="row"**>
    <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
      <label for="">Title:</label>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown"
                aria-expanded="true">
          Dropdown
          <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
          <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
      why is this left instead of right aligned??

    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Copy this code in your example and scratch the preview window to the left.

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Title:</label>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown"
            aria-expanded="true">
      Dropdown
      <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class=" form-group">
  why is this left instead of right aligned??

</div>
```

[Live example](http://plnkr.co/edit/X5KOF8?p=preview)